# to put an object in a ObjectNode of Jackson

Tags: java, json, java-8, jackson, gson

I am trying to set an `Object` in `ObjectNode` of Jackson and I am able to do that but I encountered a problem setting it into object node. the `null` attributes are also coming, using GSON I tried but then the `" \"` is coming in the request.

```
public class Testing4 {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        
            ObjectNode request = null;
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            request = mapper.createObjectNode();
            
                    
            RequestParam requestParam  = new RequestParam();
            requestParam.setCustomerName("sachin");
            requestParam.setCustomerOrderNumber("12344556");
            
            request.set("request",mapper.convertValue(requestParam, JsonNode.class));
            request.put("FatherName","jithin");
            
            String req = mapper.createObjectNode().set("request", request).toString();
            System.out.println(req);
            
            
            
        }

        private static Comparator<? super String> kFirst() {
          return (s1, s2) -> "k".equals(s1) ? -1 : "k".equals(s2) ? 1 : 0;
        
}
}
```

the DTO class

```
public class RequestParam implements Serializable {
    

        /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private String orderDueDate;
        private String originatingSystemOrderId;
        private String objectId;
        private String taskTypeId;
        private String customerId;
        private String customerName;
        private String customerOrderNumber;
        private Dataset dataset;


}
```

here  I can get the o/p  but the o/p consist of `null` assignments as well how will I remove the `null` assignments
the o/p I am getting now

```
{
  "request": {
    "request": {
      "orderDueDate": null,
      "originatingSystemOrderId": null,
      "objectId": null,
      "taskTypeId": null,
      "customerId": null,
      "customerName": "sachin",
      "customerOrderNumber": "12344556",
      "dataset": null
    },
    "FatherName": "jithin"
  }
}
```

the o/p I want

```
{
  "request": {
    "request": {
      "customerName": "sachin",
      "customerOrderNumber": "12344556"
    },
    "FatherName": "jithin"
  }
}
```

please help, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` dosent work then use

```
 @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
```

`(@JsonSerialize(include = Inclusion.NON_NULL)` don't use this its deprecated)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class RequestParam implements Serializable {

```
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private String orderDueDate;
        private String originatingSystemOrderId;
        private String objectId;
        private String taskTypeId;
        private String customerId;
        private String customerName;
        private String customerOrderNumber;
        private Dataset dataset;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class RequestParam implements Serializable {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private String orderDueDate;
        private String originatingSystemOrderId;
        private String objectId;
        private String taskTypeId;
        private String customerId;
        private String customerName;
        private String customerOrderNumber;
        private Dataset dataset;


}
```

You need to add the import statement - `import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;`

Add `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` before the DTO class definition

Comment: @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL) is giving error maybe different version of jackson

Comment: @SachinPrakash You need to add the import statement - `import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;`